# Using Python Beautifulsoup to collect data from LinkedIn

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

I'm trying to export my LinkedIn contacts names using python beautifulsoup module. my code is as bellow:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

client = requests.Session()

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'
CONNECTIONS_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/'

html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']

login_information = {
    'session_key':'username',
    'session_password':'password',
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
}
try:
    client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)
    print "Login Successful"
except:
    print "Failed to Login"

html = client.get(CONNECTIONS_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , "html.parser")
print soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'mn-connection-card__name'})
```

but the problem is I always get an empty list. like bellow:

```
Login Successful
[]
```

An html structure is like this:

```
<span class="mn-connection-card__name t-16 t-black t-bold">
      Sombody's name
    </span>
```

I think that I should change my soup.x method. I used find, select, find_all but I was not successful.

Thank you

Comment: You should be using Linkedin's [REST API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) to query this type of information.

Comment: Here's the documentation for getting connections for a user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api

Comment: Ummmmm... could it be as simple as you trying to find divs (in your code) when you should be trying to find spans (in the html structure)?

Comment: @darksky unfortunately LinkedIn limited permission in their API and because of that I need you crawl their website to gather my required info. So their REST API is not useful for now. (I need to get my contacts' email address, phone number, ...)

Comment: @Mahdi did you try replacing `'div'` with `'span'` in `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'mn-connection-card__name'})` as Jeff suggested?

Comment: @darksky yes I did, but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm late to the party, but this works for linkedin right now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#create a session
client = requests.Session()

#create url page variables
HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'
CONNECTIONS_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/'
ASPIRING_DATA_SCIENTIEST = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=Aspiring%20Data%20Scientist&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER'

#get url, soup object and csrf token value
html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find('input', dict(name='loginCsrfParam'))['value']

#create login parameters
login_information = {
    'session_key':'your_email',
    'session_password':'your_password',
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
}

#try and login
try:
    client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)
    print("Login Successful")
except:
    print("Failed to Login")

#open the html with soup object
# html = client.get(CONNECTIONS_URL).content #opens connections_url
html = client.get(ASPIRING_DATA_SCIENTIEST).content #opens ASPIRING_DATA_SCIENTIEST
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , "html.parser")
# print(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class' : 'mn-connection-card__name'}))

# print(soup)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to extract the name, all you need is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , "html.parser")
target = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class' : 'mn-connection-card__name'})
target[0].text.strip()
```

Output

```
"Sombody's name"
```

Comment: I did this, but I got list index out of range

Comment: I don't know what to tell you - I tried it again, on a clean jupyter notebook and it works for me. Just to confirm: the `html` in the `soup` variable I'm working with is `html = """
<span class="mn-connection-card__name t-16 t-black t-bold">
      Sombody's name
    </span>
"""`

Comment: could you please send your full code ? I mean authentication and etc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't do the whole thing (no LI account); just focused on the data extraction part...